# Compare if two DateTime-s have the same year, month and day in Dart

Tags: dart

Provided are `DateTime date1` and `DateTime date2` and I would need to compare if they're the same date.

A simple option is just to compare the `date1.year`, `date1.month`, `date1.day` to `date2`'s corresponding values. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: It looks like we are missing a toDate() method and a dateDifference() method in the DateTime class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing only dates of DateTimes in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978195/comparing-only-dates-of-datetimes-in-dart)

Comment: Appreciate the answer, though probably not relevant anymore as the question is 2+ years old. By memory, the problem was simple enough to solve as it's solved here (and there) without the extension. Just surprised there wasn't core support for such a comparison. Looks like there still isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the notion of "same date" – timezones can make everything very hard.

Look at `DateTime.isAtSameMomentAs`. This method could return true for `date1` and `date2` – even though they may have a different year/month/day.

Think early `Jan 1, 2019` in London and late `Dec 31, 2018` in Seattle.

Comment: Interesting. the `isAtSameMomentAs` works even when changing timezones (dart date_time package: _This relation stays the same, even when changing timezones. `assert(now.toUtc().isAtSameMomentAs(now));`_). Sadly though there isn't a similar option for dates. The equality breaks already at a 'second' level (from the dart date_time package: _`var now = new DateTime.now(); var later = now.add(const Duration(seconds: 5));assert(!later.isAtSameMomentAs(now));`_)

Answer (score 0):

**You can write an extension for easy to use:**

```dart
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  bool isSameDay(DateTime date) {
    // ignore hour,minute,second..
    final dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final date1 = dateFormat.format(this);
    final date2 = dateFormat.format(date);
    return date1 == date2;
  }
}
```

**usage:**

```dart
final date1 = DateTime(2021, 12, 10, 01, 01, 01);
final date2 = DateTime(2021, 12, 10, 23, 59, 59);
print(date1.isSameDay(date2)); // true
```