# Flutter: Check if date is between two dates

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to check date is between two dates or not.

I tried to search it but didn't got fruitful results.
May be you have seen such scenarios. So, seeking your advise.

Here is my code.

```
var service_start_date = '2020-10-17';
var service_end_date = '2020-10-23';
var service_start_time = '10:00:00';
var service_end_time = '11:00:00';

DateTime currentDate = new DateTime.now();
DateTime times = DateTime.now();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    test();
  }

 test() {
    String currenttime = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(times);
    String currentdate = DateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd').format(currentDate);
    print(currenttime);    
    print(currentdate);
    
  }
```

So, basically i have start date and end date. I need to check current date is falling between these two dates or not.

Comment: check this answer it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978195/comparing-only-dates-of-datetimes-in-dart

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am checking the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can check before/after using 'isBefore' and 'isAfter' in 'DateTime' class.
[image]

```
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.parse(service_start_date);
  DateTime endDate = DateTime.parse(service_end_date);
  
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  
  print('now: $now');
  print('startDate: $startDate');
  print('endDate: $endDate');
  print(startDate.isBefore(now));
  print(endDate.isAfter(now));
```

Comment: Just one thing i want to know. How to format the DateTime now in yyyy-mm-dd. I am talking about this  DateTime now = DateTime.now();

Comment: You can do by using 'DateFormat'. 
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);

Comment: Thanks same i did and then parse it again to datetime format to compare it. Does the same solution will apply if i need to compare the times (only) or it would be changed.

Comment: I think that all date and time can be parsed to DateTime can be compared by same solution

Comment: I am accepting the answer. Will raise another one for Time comparison.

Comment: Super.........answers

Answer (score 17):

I've made a series of extensions

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime? {
  
  bool? isAfterOrEqualTo(DateTime dateTime) {
    final date = this;
    if (date != null) {
      final isAtSameMomentAs = dateTime.isAtSameMomentAs(date);
      return isAtSameMomentAs | date.isAfter(dateTime);
    }
    return null;
  }

  bool? isBeforeOrEqualTo(DateTime dateTime) {
    final date = this;
    if (date != null) {
      final isAtSameMomentAs = dateTime.isAtSameMomentAs(date);
      return isAtSameMomentAs | date.isBefore(dateTime);
    }
    return null;
  }

  bool? isBetween(
    DateTime fromDateTime,
    DateTime toDateTime,
  ) {
    final date = this;
    if (date != null) {
      final isAfter = date.isAfterOrEqualTo(fromDateTime) ?? false;
      final isBefore = date.isBeforeOrEqualTo(toDateTime) ?? false;
      return isAfter && isBefore;
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

I'm hoping they're self explanatory but obviously you can call them like

DateTime.now().isBefore(yourDate)

DateTime.now().isAfter(yourDate)

DateTime.now().isBetween(fromDate, toDate)

Comment: i would make these booleans not nullable and return false wherever i return null

Answer (score 5):

As [@KuKu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11986450/kuku)'s answer is basically right but will set the boundaries as exclusive I want to propose a polished version of [@martinseal1987](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2745944/martinseal1987)'s answer.

```dart
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  bool isAfterOrEqual(DateTime other) {
    return isAtSameMomentAs(other) || isAfter(other);
  }

  bool isBeforeOrEqual(DateTime other) {
    return isAtSameMomentAs(other) || isBefore(other);
  }
  
  bool isBetween({required DateTime from, required DateTime to}) {
    return isAfterOrEqual(from) && isBeforeOrEqual(to);
  }
  
  bool isBetweenExclusive({required DateTime from, required DateTime to}) {
    return isAfter(from) && isBefore(to);
  }
}

// Test cases
void main() {
  final now = DateTime.now();
  final after = now.add(Duration(days: 1));
  final before = now.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
  
  print(now.isAfterOrEqual(now)); // true
  print(now.isBeforeOrEqual(now)); // true
  
  print(now.isAfterOrEqual(before)); // true
  print(now.isAfterOrEqual(after)); // false
  
  print(now.isBeforeOrEqual(after)); // true
  print(now.isBeforeOrEqual(before)); // false
  
  print(now.isBetween(from: before, to: after)); // true
  print(now.isBetween(from: now, to: now)); // true
  print(now.isBetween(from: before, to: now)); // true
  print(now.isBetween(from: now, to: after)); // true
  
  print(now.isBetweenExclusive(from: before, to: now)); // false
  print(now.isBetweenExclusive(from: now, to: after)); // false
}
```

Comment: Perfect, short and valuable support...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check if the day is the same as the one of the two dates also
by adding an or to the condition ex:
if ( start is before now || (start.month==now.month && start.day==now.day ...etc)